# Is it possible to include all javascript files from a directory using requirejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am very new to requirejs and I can't find what I am looking for in the requirejs documentation.

I have a lot of javascript files in a specific directory that I want to include using requirejs's paths. Is it possible to specify one ModuleID and then load all of the JavaScript files?

Here is a code example to illustrate what I want to do

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
   jQuery: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min",
   TheOtherStuff: "functions/*"
 }
});
```

Comment: Well combine the JS files into one module and refer this in your config. Require JS always refers each JS file as a single module. It cannot use wildcards to take all the JS file from the pointed directory as you may know client side has filesystem read restrictions. It can only take the physical path to the end of the filename.

Comment: Did you look at this module https://github.com/OpenWebStack/requirejs-glob?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to create an index.js in the functions directory that will contain all the require calls and then require

index.js:

```
define(["./minus", "./plus"], function(minus, plus) {
        //return an object to define the "functions/index" module.
        return {
            minus: minus,
            plus:  plus
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Config file:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
   jQuery: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min",
   TheOtherStuff: "functions/index"
 }
});
```

use:

```
minus = require("TheOtherStuff").minus;
plus = require("TheOtherStuff").plus
```